# click certain button using mechanize

Tags: python, web, automation, screen-scraping, mechanize

I'm trying to click a button with python and mechanize. The button looks like this:

```
<a href="#vote" target="_self" class="button primary is-xlarge expand"> <span>VOTE NOW!</span> </a>
```

when going to the link manually, (www.example.com/#vote). It doesn't work. For some reason, it needs to click the button in the browser. I believe it runs a js script as when you click the button a small menu appears, with a form.

I've tried to look at what the form is, and what my script grabs from the main site, and don't find anything close to #vote.

I need to be able to click the button, to access the form, and submit data to the form, but can't find what to 'click'.

Comment: Mechanize doesn't support JS.  I'd suggest using a webdriver-based solution.

Comment: ah ok, so like selenium?